# Script at /etc/init.d does not run at start-up

Tags: command-line, scripts, startup, init.d

I wanted to run my Dropbox daemon automatically at start-up. I did it via terminal, that is, I (1) moved it to `/etc/init.d`, (2) made it executable, and (3) ran `sudo update-rc.d dropbox.sh defaults`. So we have

```
$ ll /etc/init.d/dropbox.sh 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 38 Aug 16 00:18 /etc/init.d/dropbox.sh*

$ cat /etc/init.d/dropbox.sh 
#! /bin/sh
~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd &

$ ll ~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 skrd skrd 258 Jun  6 03:03 /home/skrd/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
```

However, Dropbox does not run upon start up.

Note that, invoking `/etc/init.d/dropbox.sh` runs the dropbox daemon without hitch.

I know that Ubuntu has a GUI for this and I could easily just add the dropbox script there but I wonder why my terminal commands didn't do it? Isn't that more standard for Linux machines?

Answer (score 2):

It may be a good way if you use `insserv` instead of `sudo update-rc.d dropbox.sh defaults`.

```
sudo insserv
```

From `man insserv`:

> ```
> insserv  is a low level tool used by update-rc.d which enables an installed sys‐
> tem init script (`boot script')
> ```

If you get the `command not found` error, you may fix by running the following command:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/insserv/insserv /sbin/insserv
```

See `insserv -h` for help.

Comment: In Ubuntu 18.10, this advice no longer works and insserv can't be installed. The advice here worked for me: https://superuser.com/a/449811/458816