# How to install an init.d script?

Tags: startup, init

I am trying to install an init.d script, to run celery for scheduling tasks.
Here is the steps I followed:

- copied the file [celeryd](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/main/extra/generic-init.d/celeryd) and pasted it in folder **/etc/init.d/**
- created a configuration file **celeryd** in folder **/etc/default/**

now when I tried to start it by `sudo /etc/init.d/celeryd start`, it throws error `sudo: /etc/init.d/celeryd: command not found`

I googled about how to install init.d, I got this [SO-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817879/how-do-i-set-up-a-init-d-script-for-a-program).

it says to issue a `uname -a` and when I does I get this:

```
Linux capsonesystem8-desktop 3.2.0-43-generic-pae 
#68-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 15 03:55:10 UTC     
2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

and also it says use utils like `insserv` to enable init.d script
so tried:

`insserv /etc/init.d/celeryd` but it throws error `insserv: command not found`

so I tried to install **insserv** `sudo apt-get install insserv`. but it say aleady installed:

```
insserv is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 222 not upgraded.
```

So how to install init.d script?? Any help will be appreciated.

#### update1:

when I tried:

```
$ sh -x /etc/init.d/celeryd start
```

it reveal some `errors`. may be that is why the service won’t start.

#### update2:

I cleared all the errors when I run `$ sh -x /etc/init.d/celeryd start` but still `sudo /etc/init.d/celeryd start` throws `command not found` error

Comment: I don't have time for an answer now, but, if you want this to run as part of your startup, then I think you have to add links to your script in the various runlevel directories so Linux will handle starting and stopping it for you. (/etc/rc[0-6].d) This process is gradually being replaced by a newer method (I think it's called upstart.), but I haven't looked into that at all. The link in your post addresses some of this.

Comment: The GitHub URL is rot.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Your `celeryd` script is probably not executable, that's why `sudo /etc/init.d/celeryd` is returning `command not found`. So, you need to first make it executable.

To do so, run the following commands:

```
sudo chmod 755 /etc/init.d/celeryd
sudo chown root:root /etc/init.d/celeryd
```

The first line changes the permissions to `-rwxr-xr-x`, and the second line ensures that the owner and group owner of the file is `root`.

Once this is done, I assume you will need to use `sudo /etc/init.d/celeryd start` to start the daemon.

Answer (score 88):

When you copy the script into place, don't forget to make it executable and owned by root:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/celeryd
sudo chown root:root /etc/init.d/celeryd
```

Once you have installed that, you can set it to start automatically on boot with:

```
sudo update-rc.d celeryd defaults
sudo update-rc.d celeryd enable
```

Comment: This would be considered as the best answer, cause of pointing to `update-rc.d`.

Answer (score 3):

If you get the `command not found` error when you run `insserv`, you may fix it by running the following command:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/insserv/insserv /sbin/insserv
```

Then see `insserv -h` or `man insserv` for help.

Also you can try with:

```
sudo update-rc.d celeryd defaults
```

Source: https://askubuntu.com/a/334043/147044

Answer (score 1):

This is command sequence to autostart your daemon at boot time:

```
sudo cd /etc/init.d
sudo chown root:root celeryd
sudo chmod 755 celeryd
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/insserv/insserv /sbin/insserv
sudo insserv celeryd
```