# How to automatically run a specific command on Live USB on boot?

Tags: live-usb, automount

I can mount my Live Ubuntu partition with this `sudo mount -o remount,rw /cdrom` what i'm asking is simple.How to make that command running automatically on every Live USB boot ?

Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place that command in a script and add the script to the init scripts. If you are using some init-alternative, place your new script where appropriate or follow what ever structure it may use for storing commands that will be executed on run-time.

If you want to know how to add scripts to init, look at this thread - [How to install an init.d script?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/335242/how-to-install-an-init-d-script-in-ubuntu)