# Dropbox on LiveCD (Persistent)

Tags: live-usb, dropbox

On a 'persistent' live-USB, the dropbox installation 'forgets' email & password, and reinstalls at every reboot. (The command line client also suffers from the same problem)

Does anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 0):

first try to run `sudo mount -o remount,rw /cdrom` on your LiveSession,it makes your read-only root partition remounted as read/write partition,then try to reinstall your dropbox.(Make sure to clean re-install,remove all left files from your computer)

I suggesting to run that first because looks like some part of DropBox need to be installed on read-only root part that will flushed every time you restart

But if it looks like that DropBox need to always write to that root part then i suggest you put that code on *init.d* also.

[How to install an init.d script?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/335242/how-to-install-an-init-d-script-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why this happens, but when storing the home dirs in `home-rw` (rather than `casper-rw`), the problem goes away.

To create 512Mb (for example) `home-rw` manually, execute:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=home-rw bs=1M count=512
mkfs.ext3 -F home-rw
```

and put it in the same location as `casper-rw`

If you already have home dirs stored in `casper-rw` you can mount  `casper-rw` and the new empty `home-rw` and move the content of `/home/` into the mounted `home-rw` root.